# how i can remove id parameter in url laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

how to change or remove the id value used in the url to call certain data, when this url appears ***localhost:8000/product/sofa/10*** i want other users to see the url just like this ***localhost:8000/product/sofa*** or ***localhost:8000/product/sofa/long*** ( rename 10 with long )

code in route

```
Route::get('/product/sofa/{id}',[ProductSofaController::class,'sofa']);
```

code in html

```
<a href="/product/sofa/{{ $id = 10 }}">
     <img loading="auto" src="{{ asset('media/category/bg-sofa.jpg') }}"
     alt="Sofa and Daybed">
</a>
```

code in controller

```
public function sofa(Request $request, $id){

    $frame = frames::where('pf_product_category_id',[$id,16])
    ->where('pf_status',true)->with('linkProducts')
    ->get();

    return view('frontend/sofa',compact('frame'));
}
```

Comment: i didnt get what you mean
you want to pass modular (for example) instead of id 10 then make the query based on that modular instead of id?

Comment: I want to hide or change the id value that is visible in the url when we access a data with reference id

Comment: So you need the `id` to query the database for your `frames`, but you don't want `id` to appear in your URL?

Comment: yes that's what it means

Comment: So how will you know which `frames` `id` to query for?

Comment: if it can't be removed, can the id value not be changed to the desired text?

Comment: If you don't want to _expose_ an `id` in your URL for identifying something, consider using a [slug](https://codebrisk.com/blog/how-to-easily-generate-slugs-for-eloquent-models-in-laravel) instead. Either that or query the database for the `id` of the category based on a name in the URL for it's `id` and join to `frames` that way.

Comment: you can use slug if you want to remove id

Comment: @rista https://www.dbestech.com/tutorials/laravel-use-slug-instead-of-id

Comment: alternatively you can submit a form with post request that will hide the query string

Answer (score 1):

You should use another function to do that, i had try that, and thats work
you can try my solution

the route :

```
Route::POST('/product/sofa/long',[ProductSofaController::class,'long']);
```

the view :

```
    <form method="POST" action="/product/sofa/long">
     <input type="hidden" name="link_id" id="link_id" value="{{ $id = 10 }}">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Input</button>
   </form>
```

the controller will look like this

```
public function long(){
 $request = [
          'li'        => $this->request->getPost('link_id'),
      ];
    $frame = frames::where('pf_product_category_id',[$id,16])
    ->where('pf_status',true)->with('linkProducts')
    ->get();

    return view('frontend/sofa',compact('frame'));
}
```

Comment: your route method is `GET` but you are calling it as a `POST` method in the form action

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Laravel slug

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
```